# The method Encrypt(long, long, long, long, int) in the type prince is not applicable for the arguments (String, long, long, long, int)

Tags: java, android, type-conversion

I could not find out why "Encrypt" function still reads "message" as string although I have changed the data type to bytes with different methods.

The error message is "The method Encrypt(long, long, long, long, int) in the type prince is not applicable for the arguments (String, long, long, long, int)".

```
btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v, String args) 
            {             
             String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
             String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();              
                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0){
                    //prince pri = new prince();
                    //message = toLong();
                    //byte[] data = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
                    //LongBuffer messageToLongBuffer;

                    //String str = message;
                    //byte[] array = str.getBytes();
                    String str = message;
                    byte[] bytes = message.getBytes();
                    prince.Encrypt (message, k0, kop, k1, t);

                    //maybe check to decrypt the ciphertext here
                    //prince.decrypt(message)
                    //sendSMS explore the sendDataMessage
                    sendSMS(phoneNo, message); }               
                else
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: `byte[]` isn't `long` either.

Comment: sorry to ask but as my lecturer told me, byte can be read as long, so you're saying it's not the same? @SLaks

Answer (score 1):

> I could not find out why "Encrypt" function still reads "message" as
>   string although I have changed the data type to bytes with different
>   methods.

LOL, change your code:

```
 byte[] bytes = message.getBytes();
 prince.Encrypt (bytes, k0, kop, k1, t); //HEREEEEEEEEEEEEE :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a new `byte[]` variable from the value of your string does not magically change the existing variable to be of type `byte[]`.

In fact, there is no way to change the type of a variable.
If you want to pass a `byte[]`, pass a `byte[]`.